# How do I deal with list of lists correctly in python? Specifically with a list of functions

Tags: python, list, variables

I am trying to grep some results pages for work, and then eventually print them out to an html website so someone does not have to manually look through each section.

**How I would eventually use:** I feed this function a result page, it greps through the 5 different sections, then I can do a html output (thats what that print substitute area is for) with all the different results.

**OK MASSIVE EDIT** I actually removed the old code because I was asking too many questions.  I fixed my code taking some suggestions, but I am still interested in the advantage of using human-readable dict instead of just list.  Here is my working code that gets all the right results into a 'list of lists', I then outputted the first section in my eventual html block

```
import urllib
import re
import string
import sys

def ipv6_results(input_page):
sections = ['/spec.p2/summary.html', '/nd.p2/summary.html',
            '/addr.p2/summary.html', '/pmtu.p2/summary.html', 
            '/icmp.p2/summary.html']
variables_output=[]                                                    
for s in sections:
    temp_list = []
    page = input_page + s
    #print page
    url_reference = urllib.urlopen(page)
    html_page = url_reference.read()
    m = re.search(r'TOTAL</B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
    temp_list.append(int(m.group(1)) )
    m = re.search(r'PASS</B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
    temp_list.append(int(m.group(1)))
    m = re.search(r'FAIL</FONT></B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
    temp_list.append(int(m.group(1)))
    variables_output.append(temp_list)

#print variables to check them :)
print "------"
print variables_output


print "Ready Logo Phase 2"
print "Section                 | Total | Pass | Fail |"
#this next part is eventually going to output an html block
output =  string.Template("""
1 - RFC2460-IPv6 Specs $spec_total $spec_pass $spec_fail
""")
print output.substitute(spec_total=variables_output[0][0], spec_pass=variables_output[0][1],
                        spec_fail=variables_output[0][2])


return 1
```

imagine the tabbing is correct :( I wish this was more like paste bin, suggestions welcome on pasting code in here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you don't declare the shape of the list first, and then fill in the values. Instead, you build the list as you discover the values.

Your `variables` has a lot of structure. You've got inner lists of 3 elements, always in the order of 'total', 'pass', 'fail'. Perhaps these 3-tuples should be made [namedtuples](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). That way, you can access the three parts with humanly-recogizable names (`data.total`, `data.pass`, `data.fail`), instead of cryptic index numbers (`data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]`).

Next, your 3-tuples differ by prefixes: `'spec'`, `'nd'`, `'addr'`, etc.
These sound like keys to a dict rather than elements of a list.

So perhaps consider making `variables` a dict. That way, you can access the particular 3-tuple you want with the humanly-recognizable `variables['nd']` instead of `variables[1]`. And you can access the `nd_fail` value with `variables['nd'].fail` instead of `variables[1][2]`:

```
import collections
# define the namedtuple class Point (used below).
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', 'total pass fail')

# Notice we declare `variables` empty at first; we'll fill in the values later.
variables={}
keys=('spec','nd','addr','pmtu','icmp')
for s in sections:
    for key in keys:
        page = input_page + s
        url_reference = urllib.urlopen(page)
        html_page = url_reference.read()
        m = re.search(r'TOTAL</B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
        ntotal = int(m.group(1)) 
        m = re.search(r'PASS</B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
        npass = int(m.group(1))
        m = re.search(r'FAIL</FONT></B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
        nfail = int(m.group(1))

        # We create an instance of the namedtuple on the right-hand side
        # and store the value in `variables[key]`, thus building the 
        # variables dict incrementally.
        variables[key]=Point(ntotal,npass,nfail)
```

Comment: this is a good learning point... 2 problems though, pass is a reserved word in python apparently :)  and this still does not solve the problem where I had the same result for spec/nd/addr/pmtu/icmp.  I was over-writing it... although I fixed that using a different method, yours is way way way more human readable, I want to re-post and see if people can help me learn 'the python way' rather than my 'very machine c way' haha  thanks for the advice here, learning everyday

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that those lists there will only be the values of the variables, at the time of assignment. You would be changing the list value, but not the variables.

I would seriously consider using classes and build structures of those, including lists of class instances.

For example:

```
class SectionResult:
  def __init__(self, total = 0, pass = 0, fail = 0):
    self.total = total
    self.pass = pass
    self.fail = fail
```

Since it looks like each group should link up with a section, you can create a list of dictionaries (or perhaps a list of classes?) with the bits associated with a section:

```
sections = [{'results' : SectionResult(), 'filename': '/addr.p2/summary.html'}, ....]
```

Then in the loop:

```
for section in sections:
   page = input_page + section['filename']
   url_reference = urllib.urlopen(page)
   html_page = url_reference.read()
   m = re.search(r'TOTAL</B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
   section['results'].total = int(m.group(1)) 
   m = re.search(r'PASS</B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
   section['results'].pass = int(m.group(1))
   m = re.search(r'FAIL</FONT></B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
   section['results'].fail = int(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary inside a list. Maybe something like:

```
def ipv6_results(input_page):
    results = [{file_name:'/spec.p2/summary.html', total:0, pass:0, fail:0},
               {file_name:'/nd.p2/summary.html', total:0, pass:0, fail:0},       
               {file_name:'/addr.p2/summary.html', total:0, pass:0, fail:0},
               {file_name:'/pmtu.p2/summary.html', total:0, pass:0, fail:0},
               {file_name:'/icmp.p2/summary.html', total:0, pass:0, fail:0}] 
    for r in results:
        url_reference = urllib.urlopen(input_page + r[file_name])
        html_page = url_reference.read()
        m = re.search(r'TOTAL</B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
        r[total] = int(m.group(1))
        m = re.search(r'PASS</B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
        r[pass] = int(m.group(1))
        m = re.search(r'FAIL</FONT></B></TD><TD>:</TD><TD>([0-9,]+)', html_page)
        r[fail] = int(m.group(1))

    for r in results:
        print r[total]
        print r[pass]
        print r[fail]
```